# Excel VBA - alt keydown event firing every other time on userform

Tags: vba, excel

first time posting, fairly new to VBA and coding.

I have an Excel 2010 userform with a button to open a spreadsheet. I have the button create a new file instead, when a modifier key is held down.

I wrote the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Debug.Print "X" & Shift
If Shift = 4 Then
    CommandButton4.Caption = "New File"
    NewFile = True
    CommandButton4.ControlTipText = "New File"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Debug.Print "Y"
CommandButton4.Caption = "Open File"
NewFile = False
CommandButton4.ControlTipText = "Open File"
End Sub
```

For every key EXCEPT Alt, both KeyDown and KeyUp events fire. For example, pressing Shift, I get a debug output:
X1
Y
X1
Y

However, pressing Alt I get:
X4
Y
Y
X4
Y
Y

Everything else in my form works correctly, but I have no idea why every other Alt KeyDown isn't registering. How can there be a KeyUp without a KeyDown?

I've searched high and low for an answer, bug report, or fix and can't find one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your challenge easily with an API call to detect if the ALT key is down.

Insert this into a new module

```
Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal key As Long) As Integer
```

and try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If GetKeyState(KeyCodeConstants.vbKeyMenu) And &H8000 Then
        MsgBox "Yes"
    Else
        MsgBox "no"
    End If
End Sub
```

`vbKeyMenu` is the ALT key. The `And &H8000` is required to look at the 'live' keystate only (the return value has another bit that is toggled on and off, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

**EDIT:**
The Phenomenon you're seeing is the following:
After you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> and see `X4 Y`, press the <kbd>down</kbd> key.
You'll see the userform's system menu pop up. The alt key follows it's purpose and moves the focus to the system menu and back to the button on the next press. If the Button has the focus, the userform obviously handles the keypress first and moves the focus to the system menu before the button receives a keydown.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, your code gives me a yes for the Alt key being down.

Comment: Ok I see. I'm a Mac user so Windows details like that don't occur to me

Comment: Well, if this helps you and answers your question, please consider to 'accept' this answer. It awards points and also shows others that this question has been solved.